# rails not creating records - routes problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**my routes**

```
TerritoryManagement::Application.routes.draw do

  get 'new' => 'territories#new', :as => 'new'

  root :to => 'territories#index', :as => 'territories'
  resources :territories
  resources :users
end
```

**create in my controller**

```
def create
  @territory = Territory.new(params[:territory])
  if @territory.save
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Product successfully created!"
  else
    render "new"
end
```

**my view**

```
<%= form_for(@territory) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**this generates**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" class="new_territory" id="new_territory" method="post">
```

I know that this `action="/"` is the problem, but I don't understand why it's being generated?  How to modify my routes that the app will create the record and then goes to the index or edit view?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
TerritoryManagement::Application.routes.draw do
   get 'new' => 'territories#new', :as => 'new'
   resources :territories
   root :to => 'territories#index'
end
```

It seems that the :as option was causing some issue. That's there to give the route a name, but since you've already done 'resources :territories' you already have named routes for the standard CRUD actions. I also moved the root route to the end of the file. I can't remember why, but it seems like this was a 'Best Practice' back in the Rails 2.3 days.

Comment: +1 this is correct.  You don't need to name the root route (:as) because it is already named root_url().  So when the form is looking for a territories route... it will use the first one it finds, which is the root_url.

Comment: That's right. I knew there was some sort of first come/first serve rule when it came to the routes file. Thanks!